# Why std::get uses template parameter instead of regular parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

The `std::get` function uses template parameter as a regular parameter.
As an example:

```
std::tuple <int, double, long &, const char *> bar(18, 6.5, 12, "Hello!");
cout << std::get<2>(bar); // Print the tuple’s third element.
```

Why this function designed this way?
Why not using a regular parameter instead?
For example, something like: `std::get(bar, 2)` or `std::get(2, bar)`

Comment: Tuples are a compile-time construct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A function must have a well-defined return type, specified at compile time. Here the template specialisation `get<2>` is a function returning `long&`; but your version would have to return a different type depending on its argument, specified at runtime, which is impossible.

Comment: I wonder if something like `std::visit` was proposed, nothing immediately shows up on my search. This would work well for a future `std::variant` as well.

Answer (score 5):

Hopefully, this demonstration is explanation enough:

```
int x;
std::cin >> x;
auto i = std::get(bar, x);
```

Keeping in mind that in C++ the type of any object must be known at compile time, what type is `i`?  Note that you cannot pass variables as template arguments, you must pass constant expressions, so the above problem doesn't exist when the integer is a template argument.

Perhaps more relevant to your example is this.

```
std::cout << std::get(bar, x);
```

Each overload of `operator<<` is a different function.  Which function to call is determined at compile time, based on the arguments.  So how can the compiler determine which overload to call in the above statement?  What if you had a tuple member which didn't even have an overload?